# hide video download button from html5 video player not working in chrome latest version - 70.0.3538.110

Tags: html, google-chrome, video-player

I have tried to remove download button option from html video player by giving controlsList="nodownload".
But it not working in chrome latest version - 70.0.3538.110.
There is a 3 dots showing in the video while its playing. when in click it, the video gets hide.
Is there any solution to hide that 3 dots from video player?
This is my screenshot - https://prnt.sc/lnge53.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working for me with this exact string:

```
<video controls controlslist="nodownload">
```

It appears to be case sensitive now? It did not work before I changed everything to lowercase.